# Scipy FFT reduce bin count

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, fft

I have a waveform `sig` that I'd like to run an FFT on. The data is sampled at 40 kHz and I want to analyze a window of 25mS or 1000 points. Using `scipy.fft.rfft(sig)` I get a resulting waveform that has 500 values. I understand these values to be magnitudes that correspond to 500 frequency bins between 0 and 20kHz. Using `scipy.fft.rfftfreq(1000, 1/40000)` we can see these bins are at intervals of 40 Hz from  0.0, 40.0, 80.0, 120.0....20000.0. I want to reduce the number of bins to 250, but still keep the same sample window and frequency range. So the results would be at 0 , 80, 160...20000. How would I achieve this? I don't see a parameter in `scipy.fft.rfft()` or `scipy.fft.rfftfreq()` to set the number of bins. I get that I can't go over 500, but I should be able to reduce the number of bins, correct?

I am coming at this problem as a EE. On a scope or spectrum analyzer I can isolate the part of the waveform I want to inspect and then there is an option to set the number of bins. My expectation is that when I reduce the number of bins, I will see less peaks, but over the same frequency range (0-20kHz). The magnitudes of neighboring peaks in the initial FFT combine in the lower bin version.

Comment: If you halve the interval over which you compute the FFT, you’ll get the result you expect.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Wouldn't that reduce my output magnitudes though?

Comment: Then take two FFTs of the two halves of your current window, and add them together. It is cheaper to do two smaller FFTs than a single larger FFT, so this will be saving you some time as well!

Comment: Ok, this seems to be doing what I'm going for, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Cris Luengo suggested, to do this without sacrificing the size of the output, break the waveform into smaller windows and then add them back together.